# Need help figuring out how to modify a Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script

I understand some programming basics and have done a small bit of coding, but it's been years. I'm WAY out of practice and need a bit of help, please.  I know the logic of what I want to do... I'm just not sure how to write, or modify an existing, script to make it happen.

I'm working with a Google Sheets spreadsheet with data regarding mobile devices that have been submitted for repair. The process I'm using right now to track devices that have been submitted for repair more than once is manual and time consuming, and I know there's got to be a way to make it easier with a script.

Here's the process I'm hoping to improve on:

1. Enter a serial number & associated data into a new row in the spreadsheet.
2. Use Ctrl-F to search to see if the serial number has been entered before.
3. Copy all rows with matching serial numbers into a separate spreadsheet.
4. Highlight the copied rows in the first spreadsheet to indicate they've been copied over onto the duplicates list.

When I've only got one or two additions to the spreadsheet at a time, doing this manual check is no big deal. But sometimes I will get a batch of dozens, even hundreds, of entries... and then it becomes very impractical.

I did a search in the scripts gallery and found this:
Find Duplicates in Selected Range
Given a selected range, this script will identify all non-blank duplicate cells, and list them. By konigsberg@google.com

That script is sort of my launching point. It's somewhat helpful... I can select the column with the serial numbers, then run this script, and it outputs a dialog box with a list of all of the serial numbers that appear more than once.

It looks like it's just dumping the output of an array, each one separated with a comma, so it's not very pretty to look at, but I can copy the list into a notepad, manually take out the commas and make it into a list, then work from that list using the manual process outlined above to make sure all of the duplicates have been copied over. The orange highlighting lets me know I've already copied a line so I'm not adding the same entry more than once. Still less than ideal, but at least it narrows down the list I have to work from.

Short term, if I could just figure out how to format the output in that dialog box so it's a little more "pretty", either separating the serial numbers with a comma and a space instead of just a comma, or listing each serial number on a new line, that would make me happier.

Ideally, if I could automate the whole comparison & copying repeats into a new spreadsheet process so I could run the script on my main spreadsheet and end up with a list containing all of the rows of data about devices that were submitted for repair more than once, that would be even better.

Or, if I could find a way to do that as I enter data, so that it would automatically check the serial number, let me know if it was a duplicate, and make sure all of the rows pertaining to that serial number have been copied into the other spreadsheet, that would be pretty awesome too.

If anyone has any suggestions on an easy(-ish) way to accomplish any of this, I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that StackOverFlow is definitely not a place to ask for readymade code and you already have a cloe vote on your post (!) but since I found this use case kind of interesting and probably useful to someone else at one time I decided to suggest a code for it.

Here is how it works : you have to define in which column is the serial number, enter in this column in an empty cell the serial number you want to get and from there run this function.

It will create a second sheet named "result : serial number" with the same headers and all the duplicates except the one you just typed in.

[test sheet shared view only, make a copy to try it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fSURLSLe-PjpK3B8lqvtmywaU10MYFxDL9Abjppz2zA/edit?usp=sharing)

### code :

```
function copyNonUniqueToSheet() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data.shift();
  var column = 1;
  var selectedRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()-2;// does not work in new version of spreadsheets for now
  Logger.log(selectedRow);
 // selectedRow = Browser.inputBox('enter row number where you entered the serial number')
  var item = data[selectedRow][column-2];
  var newSheetData = []
  newSheetData.push(headers);
  for(var n in data){
    if(n ==selectedRow){continue};// remove this line if you want to include the original occurence
    if(data[n][column-1] == item){
      newSheetData.push(data[n]);
      ss.getRange(Number(n)+2, column).setBackground('yellow');
    }
  }
  sh.insertSheet('results ('+(sh.getNumSheets())+') :'+item).getRange(1,1,newSheetData.length,newSheetData[0].length).setValues(newSheetData);    
}
```

EDIT : I just forgot that there is presently a bug in the new version of spreadsheet  : getActiveCell always return index 1... so the selection won't work. While so, use the Browser.input to enter the row number manually.

Comment: here is an example implemented in old spreadsheet version : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnZ5_ShBzI6pdDREOE5CMzZUX0JxbzFJV2U4eElINVE&usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if this was an inappropriate post - this is my first time here. I was digging through helpfiles and tutorials and whatnot on Google, and it pointed me to StackOverflow. What I needed more  than anything was sort of a push in the right direction, or confirmation that